# Is Proto-Uralic piŋз "hand, palm" related to PIE pn̥kʷstis "fist", pénkʷe "five"?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

There was Proto-Uralic piŋз "hand, palm": https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pivo#Etymology_2

I wonder whether it was related to the PIE words.

Answer (score 1):

I am unaware of any relation between the two that stands on solid ground, but there is a decent amount of loanwords between the two languages.

However, on the extremely speculative (read: controversial) side, there are a few theories that do relate those terms. Proto-Indo-Uralic and the notorious Nostratic theory both relate the terms.

In entry 1068 of the *Nostratic Dictionary (2012)* by A. Dolgopolsky, he lists:

> PIE - *de-kmt "ten" from *dwe "two" + **komt "hand with fingers"
>
> U - *käme(ne) "palm of hand"

amongst many, many others. Under the entry for "finger" lists similar derivations that include *pénkʷe.

I apologize for the transcription from the dictionary, the text is littered with a myriad of non-IPA symbols of his own invention, so I didn't even bother with them.